# Backround Gif non displaying in Github Pages website

Tags: html, css, github, background-image, gif

I'm hosting a website with GItHub Pages. In my index.html file, i have a section called `'hero'`. Here is the code:

```html
<section id="hero" style="background-image: url(./assets/img/gif.gif);">
more code
  </section>
```

For some reason when i load up the page (username.github.io) The background is grey. Maybe the file is too big? Or maybe GP doesn't support gifs?

I tried putting the css part in both the html file (as shown above) and the css file, but still nothing. I also tried with ./assets/, /assets/, assets/, but nothing. Also tried with background: url() instead of background-image. Even putting https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/username/reponame/main/assets/img/gif.gif, or putting .GIF instead of .gif.